# D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

Tags: android, file, ringtone

This one is driving me nuts!

I am working in Android Studio and using a Huawei device to run the app. (Not using the emulator)

I am just trying to add an alarm tone when the counter in my program reaches zero. There is no sound and I get the following messages on console when I reach this line,

```
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri
    RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
```

D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

E/MediaPlayer: Unable to to create media player

D/Ringtone: Problem opening; delegating to remote player

W/RingtoneManager: prepare failed ......

I cannot see why the default alarm tone cannot be found. FYI I have tried "TYPE_NOTIFICATION" and "TYPE_RINGTONE" in all cases file couldn't be opened.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Paul